# backend with ajax to detect if user is no longer active

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a heartbeat that runs at a set interval, to make sure the user is still on the page. Which I've done:

```
(function worker() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/users/' + <%= current_user.id %> + '/heartbeat', 
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('updated')
    },
    complete: function() {
      setTimeout(worker, 5000);
    }
  });
})();
```

now what I'd like to do on the backend is change the status to `current_user.inactive!` if it doesn't receive an update for say 30 seconds. I'm assuming a lot of you have done something similar in an app, and I want to get a feel for the best way to do this?

Is it to have it update a column in the DB and have a background job constantly running? or is there some much more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

I would put that functionality in my "check-session" filter. I.e., whenever you process a request, in addition to making sure that the user is logged in etc., you also check if his session timed out.

EDIT: example pseudo code

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base        
  before_filter do
     session = ...   # an ActiveModel instance 
     raise "Timeout" if session.last_action < 60.minutes.ago
     session.last_action = Time.now
     session.save!
  end
end
```

The other controllers then inherit from `ApplicationController` as usual.

By the way, you probably don't want to have the heartbeat on the *user*, but on his *session*, right? If you're sure you want it on the user, replace `session` with `user` in the pseudo code, of course.

Refinement is left to you, i.e. you probably do not want to put a timeout on your `LoginController`... :-)

Comment: Any example code here? Trying to see if it fits my case. In my case a user can be live on the site and await an assignment (actioncable) so I'd like for the user to be made inactive, if they leave the site.